# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar

Tags: java, node.js, angular, maven

I am working on an end-to-end project which includes backend and frontend. The frontend works fine (angular2 framework, the 'npm start' and 'ng build' works). However, when I run 'mvn clean install' from the project home folder, it gives me an error where I have no clue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) on project frontend: Error assembling JAR: Failed to determine inclusion status for: .\frontend\pom.xml: The request is not supported. -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: ...
```

Under the project home folder, I can run 'mvn compile' successfully, but not 'mvn clean install'. It shows frontend Failure with the error message above, backend Skip.

The maven settings.xml is the original one. I have correct setting of Java Home.

Can you help me?

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xlinq.gtool</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for X-LinQ Graphical Tool</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>frontend</module>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>




</project>
```

fronted POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

    <name>frontend</name>
    <description>The X-LinQ frontend project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xlinq.gtool</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v6.10.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/frontend</directory>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>




</project>
```

Response:

```
> mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent
[INFO] frontend
[INFO] backend
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ parent ---
[INFO] Installing H:\project\pom.xml to C:\Users\x\.m2\repository\com\xlinq\gtool\parent\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\parent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building frontend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Deleting H:\project\frontend\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Node v6.10.3 is already installed.
[INFO] NPM 3.10.10 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm (npm install) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in H:\project\frontend\src\main\frontend
[WARNING] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
[WARNING] npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm (npm run build) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run build' in H:\project\frontend\src\main\frontend
[INFO]
[INFO] > gtool@0.0.0 build H:\project\frontend\src\main\frontend
[INFO] > ng build
[INFO]
[INFO] Hash: 46436a79c4d4bc172d29
[INFO] Time: 52660ms
[INFO] chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 177 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
[INFO] chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 104 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
[INFO] chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 270 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
[INFO] chunk    {3} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 733 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
[INFO] chunk    {4} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 6.01 MB [initial] [rendered]
[INFO] chunk    {5} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
[ERROR]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 36 resources to static
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ frontend ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory H:\project\frontend\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ frontend ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ frontend ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ frontend ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.350 s]
[INFO] frontend ........................................... FAILURE [03:06 min]
[INFO] backend ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-16T15:27:21+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/357M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) on project frontend: Error assembling JAR: Failed to determine inclusion status for: H:\project\frontend\pom.xml: H:\project\frontend\pom.xml: The request is not supported. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :frontend
```

Comment: You should provide more information for people helping you.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem. Nothing wrong with the POM and Maven settings.xml. The problem is that the project was mounted in a network location. After moving it to a local hard disk drive, the mvn clean install works.

Comment: saved my day tnx!

Comment: I've had similar problems with this plugin - version 2.4 will work against a network path.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly a mounted WSL drive is considered a network mount as well as that is where I'm seeing it.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar
```

and

```
Error assembling JAR: Failed to determine inclusion status for
```

were messages that I am seeing.  This was not a problem with previous versions of the maven-jar-plugin (2.5)